# Samba share not mounting on Linux CLI client (works on GUI)

Tags: samba, cifs

I configured Samba server in RHEL 7.3 with following:

- `mkdir /samba-share`
- with `chmod 777 /samba-share`
- firewall and selinux is stoped.

Configuration:

```
[global]
workgroup=MYGRP
security= user
passdb backend= tbdsam

[samba-share]
path=/samba-share
public = no
browseable=yes
writable=yes
valid users = smbuser
```

From RHEL 7 client I use:

```
mount –t cifs 192.168.0.1:/samba-share /tmp-samba/ –o username=smbuser,workgroup=MYGRP
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

The same configuration is working in GUI and it also works on Windows 7 client. Only the command line is giving this error.

Comment: Did you notice you are using a wrong username (smbuser1 vs smbuser) and workgroup (MYGROUPANIS vs MYGRP)?